# Actionscript 3: How do I get date from server (not client)

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a Christmas calendar for my school, when I noticed that, the Date-class is not what I though it was.

It gets the time from the client CPU, and that won't do.

So, I been looking around on the web, but there have been no good answers (at least that I could make any sense of).

So here it is:

How do i get the time and date (*) in UTC +1, from the server my flash-program are hosted, or some external time-server?

**In UNIX-time, or somehow else actionscript 3 can understand*

My search for answers had suggestions for some php-scripts, but i don't understand how to use that (there where a few examples, but they where in AS2).

Comment: What server/hosting do you have?

Comment: my host is Hosting24.com
I got full access to the files with FTP, and a file-browser with whats called "cPanel". 
My website is www.grambogames.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more secure way of doing this (eg not using flash vars which can be tampered with), would be to create a very simple server page (outputs plain text instead of html) that outputs the date, then load that into flash with a loader and parse it into a native `Date` object.

The flash side would look like this:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
loader.load(new URLRequest("your server page"))
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded)
function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    var date:Date;
    try{
        date = new Date(Number(loader.data)); //need to cast the loader data as a number
    }catch(e:Error){
    }

    if(!date){
        //your output from the server isn't formatted in a way flash can convert it
        date = new Date(); //use local time
    }
}
```

---

The reason for using try/catch, is because if output from the server isn't a valid date it will throw an error when trying to convert it.  If an error is thrown anywhere inside of a try block, it will exit at the line of the error (skip the rest of the code) and run what is in the catch block.  If there is no error in the try block, the code in the catch block will never run.

---

With PHP  (though I don't have php anywhere handy to check so this may need to be corrected by someone, and it's been about 10 years since I've programmed with it)

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print time() * 1000;
?>
```

Comment: I got a major question, and a minor question, as well as a thank you. 1: how do I write the server-page you suggest? 2:what do try and catch do? 3: Thank you for helping.

Comment: Question 1 depends on what server side programming language you use. (PHP, ASP, JSP etc). If you let me know which one(s) you can use, I'll include a sample in the answer.  I've update the question to explain try/catch

Comment: Well, given that I got root access, I believe that any language will do. But since I never heard of ASP or JPS, it should be php (I got some understanding of it).

Comment: I put a php example in my answer, don't have a way to test it though so you may need to experiment a bit.

Comment: thank you, it looks like it works. I will experiment more later, to make sure there are no unexpected bugs or errors. on that topic, I got one bug: the "time()" function from the php-script returns time in milliseconds, not seconds, it should not be multiplied by 1000. (worth fixing here in case of other people who needs help for the same problem).

Comment: Ah, for some reason I remembered it being seconds.  Corrected the answer

Comment: ok... now I'm just cunfused...

It looks like it comes in secounds after all...
Anyway, I uploaded the test, but when I test the time, it keeps fallowing the client-time. However, when running the flash-file locally on my computer, it works as expected, and keeps fallowing servertime.

Its in Norwegian, but have a look for yourself http://www.grambogames.net/julekalender/ the clock is in the left-top corner.

Comment: What is the url of your php page?  The code in my answer will revert to local time (via the try/catch) if the server time it receives can't be converted to a flash Date.

Comment: I been thinking, it might be that the flash-program fails to load the server-time, so the failsafe(client-time) kicks in... anyway, the page with the time is http://grambogames.net/serverTime.php

Comment: So the result from that page is in seconds, so you'll want to multiply it by 1000.  I found the issue, the Date() needs the value to be a number, not a string.  I'll update the answer

Comment: You know what? I think it finally works. I don't know why, but when I test now, its no longer fallowing the client-time. Anyway, I DID get what I needed, so again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the date to the swf file like this:

```
<param name=FlashVars value="date=<?php date(); ?>" />
```

You can read more about how to pass date to the swf file here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html
And more about how to format the date here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

In this variant to have to rename your .html file to .php.

Comment: this is a good answer though and a perfectly acceptable method if tampering isn't a concern.

Comment: I will have a close look at this later, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I was very short in time. But should be fine for a simple datestring. Hope it helps. Otherwise ask.

Answer (score 0):

So to summerize, the answer is a php-script containing only this:

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
print time();
?>
```

and the script I use to get the time from the server is:

```
//cut from a larger script
{
loader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://grambogames.net/serverTime.php"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onServerTimeLoad);
trace("waiting for time to load");
}



private function onServerTimeLoad(e:Event):void
{
trace("date loaded:", loader.data);
try
{
    var num:Number = Number(loader.data) * 1000
    dato = new Date(num);
    trace("tid & dato synkronisert med server.", dato);
}
catch (e:Error)
{
    //the passed date was invalid, lets just use the local system date
    dato = new Date();
    trace("date did not work, local time used");
    txt_error.text = "ERROR! COULD NOT GET TIME FROM SERVER!"
}
    if (! dato)
{
    //your output from the server isn't formatted in a way flash can convert it
    trace("not working, date farmated wrong");
}
}
```

thanks to LondonDrugs_MediaServices

...I just hope no more bugs shows up.