# Get Time from Server

Tags: php, actionscript-3, date, time, server

In Actionscript3 I need to get the time from a server, not from Date() because this can be manipulated by simply changing the computers date. I found this answer: [Actionscript 3: How do I get date from server (not client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519987/actionscript-3-how-do-i-get-date-from-server-not-client)

So I wrote this PHP-File and uploaded it to the Server as serverTime.php:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print time() * 1000;
?>
```

Then in the Actionscript-Class I wrote:

private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

```
private function myFunction () : void {
    loader.load(new URLRequest("myServerDomain/serverTime.php"));
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
}

private function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    var date:Date;
    try{
            date = new Date(Number(loader.data));
        }
    catch(e:Error){}

    if(!date){
        date = new Date();
    }

    trace (date + " " + loader.data);
}
```

The problem now is, that the trace writes an invalid Date for 'date' and the 'loader.data' just gives the whole PHP-Text back, like this:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    print time() * 1000;
?>
```

It doesn't return a Number as it was needed. So the time() doesn't work and I also only should get a Number out of the PHP.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you got the php code returned that's mean the php script is not executed which mean a configuration problem in your web server, so verify that you can run php in your server !

Comment: What kind of server are you running?  does your page have a .php extension and is PHP installed on the server?  Currently your server is treating the page like plain text or html and it is not being parsed by PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!! How could i verify that my server runs PHP and how could I install PHP on my server?

Comment: Or would there be an alternative way to get the server time?

Comment: @wolga Which kind of OS are you using ? For windows, you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), and you can use [MAMP](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16197/mamp) for mac, for Linux you can find many tutos to how to install a web server according to your distribution ...